# FB Authentication goes from Fanpages to app page and not back to fanpage

Tags: php, authentication, facebook-page

I'm using php and running my app on different fanpages but when a new users goes to authenticate it always redirects them to the app page after authentication.
I did try getting the fanpage id and name from $signed_request but it fails because the authentication needs to go first so I can't redirect back to the fan page.
If anyone knows how I can get an app to authenticate from a fanpage and go back there I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect back to page tab after user authenticates?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8158657/redirect-back-to-page-tab-after-user-authenticates)

Comment: Yes I looked at that but none of them work because :-
You can't get a $signed_request page info until the page is authentcated and by then its already on the app page.
2 You can't store in a database and retrieve because you still don't know which page your actually on due to the reason in 1.

Comment: No this is not **true**. Facebook *will* send you the page info even without authorization. The only difference here is the user info. Facebook **will not** send you the user *detailed* info until the user explicitly authorize your app. (you'll only receive age range, country..etc)

Comment: Are you sure because thats virtually the first thing I do, use $signed_request to check which page im on, when the app has been authorised it gives me page details if the app hasn't yet been authorised it doesn't.

Comment: Of course I'm sure, check my [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/determine-if-the-user-likes-fan-of-your-page-when-landing-on-your-page-tab/29/). **PLEASE NOTE** if you have any kind of redirection then the `signed_request` will be lost.

Comment: Thanks ifaour I retested taking out the redirect and it gathered the data so now I can progress from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook POST the `signed_request` to your app (whether it's in a page tab or canvas). So doing a redirect *before* capturing the `signed_request` would cause a loss of the data.

Solutions:

- Avoid unnecessary redirects.
- Save the `signed_request` to the session before the redirect or just add it (as a query string) for the next URL

Comment: OK well I rewrote my app and now it gets pageid for the fanpage and the app id of the app and displays it as a link to go back to the fanpage.
But if you click on the link in the app fb comes back with a warning "This content can't be displayed in a frame".

Comment: try adding a `target="_top"` to the link. this way, the whole window will get redirected.

Comment: Thanks again ifaour
 I also found a javascript script 
`code`echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">top.location.href = '$url';</script>";